# Providing MySQL a manually-typed list of rows to left join with?

Tags: mysql

My Google-Fu is weak on this one, so mayhaps you all can help.

If you want to select multiple columns, you can do...

`SELECT 'something' as userName, 'fooBar' as typicalSaying`

And you'd get:

```
+----------------+-----------------+
|    userName    |   typicalSaying |
+----------------+-----------------+
|   something    |    fooBar       |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

However, how do I do the above with rows?

EG:

```
SELECT someLine, effy.text from table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'a' as text UNION 'b' UNION 'c') as effy
```

**EDIT:**
To get a result like..

```
+----------------+--------------+
|    someLine    |   effy.text  |
+----------------+--------------+
|   entryA       |    a         |
|   entryA       |    b         |
|   entryA       |    c         |
+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'However, how do I do the above with rows?'?

Comment: Thanks for the confusion, Jcho360. I edited my question to show the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
SELECT someLine, effy.text
FROM table
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 'a' as text
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c'
) as effy
```

Comment: That's really lame that there's no way of doing it without UNION statements.  Sigh. :|  Thanks!

Comment: Well, in MSSQL you could use `VALUES (),(),...`, similar to MySQL's `INSERT VALUES (),(),..`. But in MSSQL you can only `INSERT .. UNION ... UNION`:) See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/ (based on some quick googling)